# Best way to replace every third character in a string in delphi

Tags: string, delphi, delphi-5

What's the most efficient way to replace every third character of the same type in a string?

I have a string like this:

```
str := 'c1'#9'c2'#9'c3'#9'c4'#9'c5'#9'c6'#9'
```

I want to replace every third #9 by #13#10, so that i get:

```
str1 := 'c1'#9'c2'#9'c3'#13#10'c4'#9'c5'#9'c6'#13#10'
```

I would do this in this way:

```
i:=0;
newStr:='';
lastPos := Pos(str,#9);

while lastPos > 0 do begin
  if i mod 3 = 2 then begin
    newStr := newStr + Copy(str,1,lastPos-1) + #13#10;    
  end else begin
    newStr := newStr + Copy(str,1,lastPos);
  end;

  str := Copy(str,lastPos+1,MaxInt);
  i := i + 1;
  lastPos := Pos(str,#9);
end;

newStr := Copy(str,1,MaxInt);
```

But thats a lot of copying. Is there a string manipulation function to do this?

Comment: Questions about Optimizing working code would fit for [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Since you are replacing one char by two chars there is no solution that does not involve at least resizing the string. But you could count the occurences first and then resize the string accordingly and move the parts to the right filling in the replaced characters.

Comment: Define "most efficient" please. What's the input data?

Comment: You need to copy the original characters anyways, so you will end up doing a lot of assignments. You can resize the original string and move chars around using memory operations, but you need to know your types. That's why David asked what's the input data.

Comment: Are you sure you want to replace each 3rd character, or do you want to replace all tabs? In the last case use StringReplace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem as stated doesn't match the code you provided. Is every third character a #9? If so, do you want to change every third appearance of #9 for #13#10?

If so, I would do it this way:

```pascal
function test(str: string): string;
var
  i, c, l: integer;
begin
  l := Length(str);
  SetLength(Result, l + l div 9);
  c := 1;
  for i := 1 to l do
  begin
    if (i mod 9 = 0) and (i > 0) then
    begin
      Result[c] := #13;
      Inc(c);
      Result[c] := #10;
    end
    else
      Result[c] := str[i];
    Inc(c);
  end;
end;
```

I actually have no idea if this function performs well. But given that the constraints aren't clear, I guess so.

If the position of the #9 character is unknown then this solution won't work at all.

**Edit**: as David points out, this is not nearly equivalent to the original code posted. This seems to work, but it requires two passes on the original string. The thing is, to know if its more efficient or not we need to know more about the input and context.

```
function OccurrencesOfChar(const S: string; const C: char): integer;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  result := 0;
  for i := 1 to Length(S) do
    if S[i] = C then
      inc(result);
end;

function Test(str: string): string;
var
  len, n, C, i: integer;
begin
  C := 1;
  len := Length(str);
  n := OccurrencesOfChar(str, #9);
  SetLength(result, len + n div 3);
  n := 1;
  for i := 1 to len do
  begin
    if str[i] = #9 then
    begin
      if n mod 3 = 0 then
      begin
        result[C] := #13;
        inc(C);
        result[C] := #10;
      end
      else
        result[C] := #9;
      Inc(n);
    end
    else
      result[C] := str[i];
    inc(C);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This code is functionally different from the code in the question. So it really has no place here. And since the questions asks about performance your declaration that "I actually have no idea if this function performs well" seems almost confessional. You've admitted defeat.

Comment: Sorry, my explanation was not clear. You are right I want to change every third appearance of #9 by #13#10.

Comment: The input data is kind of a table. Each #9 marks a new column and after every third #9 there is a new row.

Answer (score 0):

I expect this question will be closed, but just for fun, that would be my proposal.

```
Function Replace(const Instr:String;Re:Char;const ReWith:String):String;
var
 i,o,cnt,l:Integer;
begin
  cnt:=0;
  o:=0;
  SetLength(Result,Length(Instr)*Length(ReWith));// just for security
  for I := 1 to Length(Instr) do
      begin
        if Instr[i]=Re then inc(cnt);
        if cnt=3 then
          begin
            for l := 1 to Length(ReWith) do
                begin
                 inc(o);
                 Result[o] := ReWith[l];
                end;
           cnt := 0;
          end
        else
          begin
            inc(o);
            Result[o] := Instr[i];
          end;
      end;
  SetLength(Result,o);
end;


procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Edit2.Text := Replace(Edit1.Text,'A','xxx')
end;
```

Comment: That "just for security" part smells funny - also, the OP is asking replacing every third character by two characters, not finding a char and then replacing it every third time...

Comment: @Leonardo - this routine can be improved in various ways (for efficiency), but the "just for security" part is perfectly fine, albeit also inefficient (in terms of use of space).  It basically says "let's assume that we will replace every character with the replacement string, so the maximum length of our result string is the length of the input string * the length of the char replacement.  "security" is probably the wrong word to use here.  "efficiency" would be more appropriate as this (common) technique avoids having to constantly re-alloc the result string as it "grows".

Comment: @Deltics - I understand the principle behind allocation, but you shouldn't over allocate. That's lazy!

Comment: @Leonardo - lazy or not, it's perfectly safe in this implementations so the question is whether it's the most efficient.  By eliminating the need to have an addition iteration over the input string to pre-calculate the result length, it arguably meets the OP's constraint of "most efficient", w.r.t performance (though there are possibly other areas that could be improved in this respect).  Then again, it is the **least** efficient in terms of (transient) memory use.  Hence David's point about "most efficient" being incompletely defined.

Comment: Max length would be something like: `Length(Instr) + ((Length(Instr) div 3) + 1)*(Length(ReWith)-1)`.

Comment: @Leonardo Over allocating likely to perform better. Correct allocation involves multiple passes over the data.

Comment: @LURD I agree and thought about ... it's cheap as it is, for expected big strings I'd work with streams.

Comment: I love these small problems. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like this (coded in the browser). It only needs one string resize and should have less movement of data around. I exit when I have made the last replacement or if it didn't need any:

```
procedure ReplaceXChar(var aStringToReplace: string; const aIteration: 
    Integer; const aChar: Char; const aReplacement: string);
var
  replaceCount: Integer;
  cntr: Integer;
  outputCntr: Integer;
  lengthToReplace: Integer;
begin
  // Find the number to replace
  replaceCount := 0;
  for cntr := 1 to Length(aStringToReplace) do
  begin
    if aStringToReplace[cntr] = aChar then
      Inc(replaceCount);
  end;
  if replaceCount >= aIteration then
  begin
    // Now replace them
    lengthToReplace := Length(aReplacement);
    cntr := Length(aStringToReplace);
    SetLength(aStringToReplace, cntr + 
        (replaceCount div aIteration) * (lengthToReplace - 1));
    outputCntr := Length(aStringToReplace);
    repeat
      if aStringToReplace[cntr] = aChar then
      begin
        if (replaceCount mod aIteration) = 0 then
        begin
          Dec(outputCntr, lengthToReplace);
          Move(aReplacement[1], aStringToReplace[outputCntr+1], 
              lengthToReplace * SizeOf(Char));
        end
        else
        begin
          aStringToReplace[outputCntr] := aStringToReplace[cntr];
          Dec(outputCntr);
        end;
        Dec(replaceCount);
      end
      else
      begin
        aStringToReplace[outputCntr] := aStringToReplace[cntr];
        Dec(outputCntr);
      end;
      Dec(cntr);
    until replaceCount = 0;
  end;
end;
```

Usage would be like this:

```
var
  myString: String;
begin
  myString := 'c1'#9'c2'#9'c3'#9'c4'#9'c5'#9'c6'#9;
  ReplaceXChar(myString, 3, #9, #13#10);
  ShowMessage(myString);
end;
```